# Cannot Connect to Database Server - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mysql-workbench

I have a problem connecting to the local database

[image]

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['username'] = 'Atlas';
$db['default']['password'] = '123456';
$db['default']['database'] = 'erphitech';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $db['default']['hostname'] should be the location for the database (localhost if your development in local)

Comment: I've tried it, still doesn't work. I get the same error

Comment: Did you check the 4 points from your screenshot?

Comment: Works now :) earlier I was changing it only in my code and not in workbench. But now I have another error in my browser: A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 347